# How to store language strings with a variable in the middle, Php

Tags: php, string

I have strings that are sprinkled through a few classes making changes difficult. What I would like to do is have a config function that puts all the strings into variables and are used in the program so I only have to edit one function. (PHP)

My question is how could I  have a string (or other data type) that allows me to concatinate later. For example:

```
$vars = array('one', 'two', 'red', 'blue');
foreach($vars as $var) {
     echo "List all rows with <strong>$var</strong> in the column.<br/>";
}
```

> List all rows with **one** in the column.
>   List all rows with **two** in the column.
>   List all rows with **red** in the column.
>   List all rows with **blue** in the column.

I would like to hold onto "List all rows with **$var** in the column." in one place and then add in the $var in another function at another time. I know I could just hold onto two variables or put it in an array but I felt like there must be some data structure that I was missing that could make this job easier.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), you don't have to worry about variable naming.

```
$string = "List all rows with <strong>%s</strong> in the column.<br/>";
$var = "herp";

printf($string, $var);

function something() {
  $something_else = 'derp';
  printf($string, $something_else);
}

something();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php    
$str = "blah blah blah {var}";
....
$output = str_replace("{var}",$someVar,$str);
```

Good sollution, @Andrej. But a tune up:

```
<?php
$search = array("{name}"); 
$replace = array($name); 
$var = str_replace($search, $replace, "My name is {name}");
```

Comment: But preg_replace is taking more time. If you don't really need regullar expressions, it's better not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "blah blah blah {var}";
....
$output = str_replace("{var}",$someVar,$str);
```

Read about templaters.

Answer (score 1):

look at [PHP array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function